# Why am i unable to open a script in UNITY

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I created a script called collision but when i click on it to open it visual studio opens other scripts in my game.
I use the community edition of visual studio 2019. I am creating a game in UNITY 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching between files in the scripts folder, on the right side you should see them.